# Read dbus property with Python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, bluetooth, dbus, bluez

I am trying to read the Bluetooth address of a Raspberry Pi from dbus. I can do it with busctl from the command line as detailed below, but the Python code that seems like it should run the same procedure fails. I get the same failure when reading other properties from dbus. I can get the address by the unsatisfactory method of running hciconfig as a sub process, but what's wrong with the Python code?

```
1. List dbus bluez with busctl 

  busctl introspect org.bluez /org/bluez/hci0
  produces this (edited) result:

  NAME                                TYPE      SIGNATURE RESULT/VALUE           FLAGS
  org.bluez.Adapter1                  interface -         -                      -
  .GetDiscoveryFilters                method    -         as                     -
  .Address                            property  s         "DC:A6:32:04:DB:56"    emits-change
  .AddressType                        property  s         "public"               emits-change
  org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable interface -         -                      -
  .Introspect                         method    -         s                      -
  org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties     interface -         -                      -
  .Get                                method    ss        v                      -
  .GetAll                             method    s         a{sv}                  -
  .Set                                method    ssv       -                      -
  .PropertiesChanged                  signal    sa{sv}as  -                      -


2. Read Address with busctl

  busctl get-property org.bluez /org/bluez/hci0 org.bluez.Adapter1 Address

  produces this correct result:
    s "DC:A6:32:04:DB:56"

  this is from dbus-monitor:
  
  method call time=1653300359.259826 sender=:1.43 ->
       destination=org.bluez serial=2 
       path=/org/bluez/hci0;
       interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties;
       member=Get
          string "org.bluez.Adapter1"
          string "Address"
  method return time=1653300359.259940 sender=:1.8 ->
     destination=:1.43 serial=85 reply_serial=2
     variant       string "DC:A6:32:04:DB:56"



3. Python3 code to do the same thing as follows:

  bus = dbus.SystemBus() 
  obj = bus.get_object("org.bluez","/org/bluez/hci0") 
  interface = dbus.Interface(obj,"org.freedesktop.Dbus.Properties")
  address = interface.Get("org.bluez.Adapter1","Address")

  produces this result:
  
  bus = runs OK
  obj = runs OK
  interface = runs OK
  address = fails with following error:  
    Method "Get" with signature "ss" on interface "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties"  doesn't exist

  BUT IT DOES! and it works for busctl 

  address = interface.Get()
  address = interface.Get("org.bluez.Adapter1")
  address = interface.GetAll()
  address = interface.GetAll("org.bluez.Adapter1")
  address = obj.Get("org.bluez.Adapter1","Address",dbus_interface="org.freedesktop.Dbus.Properties")
    also fail with the same error
```

Comment: Do you run your script with "root" permission?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line of your code:

```
interface = dbus.Interface(obj,"org.freedesktop.Dbus.Properties")
```

should actually be

```
interface = dbus.Interface(obj,"org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties")
```

Comment: To save you having to type `org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties` and getting the capitalization wrong, there is a constant in the `dbus` library: `dbus.PROPERTIES_IFACE` so you can put: `interface = dbus.Interface(obj, dbus.PROPERTIES_IFACE)`

Answer (score 1):

For the python code you might find it easier to use D-Bus bindings that are more Pythonic.

I find [pydbus](https://pypi.org/project/pydbus/) easy to use.

Below is your example with Pydbus:

```py
(venv) pi@raspberry:~$ python3
Python 3.9.2 (default, Mar 12 2021, 04:06:34) 
[GCC 10.2.1 20210110] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pydbus
>>> bus = pydbus.SystemBus() 
>>> adapter = bus.get('org.bluez', '/org/bluez/hci0')
>>> adapter.Address
'B8:27:EB:22:57:E0'
>>> dir(adapter)
['ActiveInstances', 'Address', 'AddressType', 'Alias', 'Class', 'Discoverable', 'DiscoverableTimeout', 'Discovering', 'Get', 'GetAll', 'GetDiscoveryFilters', 'Introspect', 'Modalias', 'Name', 'Pairable', 'PairableTimeout', 'Powered', 'PropertiesChanged', 'Register', 'RegisterAdvertisement', 'RegisterApplication', 'RegisterEndpoint', 'RegisterPlayer', 'RemoveDevice', 'Roles', 'Set', 'SetDiscoveryFilter', 'StartDiscovery', 'StopDiscovery', 'SupportedIncludes', 'SupportedInstances', 'SupportedSecondaryChannels', 'UUIDs', 'Unregister', 'UnregisterAdvertisement', 'UnregisterApplication', 'UnregisterEndpoint', 'UnregisterPlayer', '_Introspect', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_bus', '_bus_name', '_object', '_path', 'onPropertiesChanged']
>>> adapter.GetDiscoveryFilters()
['UUIDs', 'RSSI', 'Pathloss', 'Transport', 'DuplicateData', 'Discoverable', 'Pattern']
>>>
```

If you want to continue using the dbus library then there are lots of example in the BlueZ source tree at: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/test